# Routing to new controller with $state.go and calling function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Having trouble finding any docs or discussions related to this issue.  I see how to pass parameters url style (ie: param1=var1,param2=var2).  But how do I use $state.go to navigate to another controller and call a function in that controller at the same time?

`$state.go("clubs") ;`

And need to call `$scope.addClubs(var1,var2)` from the "clubs" page.

I suppose I could pass parameters like:
     `doAction=1&param1=var1&param2=var2`

And in the:

```
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
     //process parameters
     if (doAction == 1) {
        $scope.addClub(param1,param2) ;
     }
  }
```

but is their a cleaner way of doing this by simply calling the function from the original $state.go("clubs") call?

Comment: Refactor the controllers to put business logic into a service. Service functions can be called from any controller. That way the controllers are simplified and only contain view logic.

Comment: you mean call like an `init` method?